# solution to $\tan(\frac{t-s}{2}).(v_t-v_s)=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I end ep with the canonical form of the a PDE as: $$\tan(\frac{t-s}{2}).(v_t-v_s)=0$$
then I am about to find the general solution: $$v_t=v_s \iff ds=dt \iff s=t+c$$
Is it true?

Comment: $$v_{t} - v_{s} = 0 \implies v = f(t + s)$$

where $f$ is any differentiable function.